# Error reading xls or csv with php joomla

Tags: php, csv, joomla, xls

I want to get data from a csv or xls excel to make a massive load of employees in my mysql DB, but first show all records in a table. the project is in php with joomla ..

I tried this:

```
. include JPATH_SITE '/ libraries / simpleexcel / src / SimpleExcel / SimpleExcel.php';
JHTML :: addIncludePath (JPATH_SITE '/ libraries / excel / reader.php'.)


$ name = $ _POST ['name'];

Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader $ data = new ();
$ data-> setOutputEncoding ('CP1251');
$ data-> read ($ name);
echo ("<table>");
for ($ i = 1; $ i <= $ data-> sheets [0] ['numRows']; ++ $ i) {
     echo ("<tr>");
     for ($ j = 1, $ j <= $ data-> sheets [0] ['NumCols']; ++ $ j) {
         echo ("<td>" $ data-> sheets [0] ['cells'] [$ i] [$ j] "</ td>"..);
     }
     echo ("</ tr>");
  }
```

but apparently no problem to import the library

nor recognizes this:

```
_FILES ['File'] ['name'] $
```

If anyone can help, thanks. !!

Comment: I'm assuming the actual code you're using does not have all the extra spaces in it, so I'll venture a guess and say that you're using $_POST['name'] instead of $_FILES['File']['name'], but it's hard to tell if this is not the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

**OOPS** - I misread your spreadsheet library, thinking it was [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). I believe this will still generally work, just adjust for SimpleExcel.

I just tried this code and it worked as expected. you'll need to put in the values that work from your site, and the name of the file that is being uploaded, then adjust the table output you want.

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define ('JPATH_BASE', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\mysite');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/PathToPhpExcel/PHPExcel.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/PathToPhpExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php' );

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

// Get spreadsheet file name from $_FILES
$spreadsheet = 'c:\path\to\your\spreadsheet.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($spreadsheet);
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$doImport = false;
if($doImport)
    jimport('joomla.user.helper');

echo "<table>";
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $r = $row->getRowIndex();
    $udata = array(
        "name"=>$worksheet->getCell('A'.$r)->getCalculatedValue(),
        "username"=>$worksheet->getCell('B'.$r)->getCalculatedValue(),
        "password"=>$worksheet->getCell('C'.$r)->getCalculatedValue(),
        "password2"=>$worksheet->getCell('C'.$r)->getCalculatedValue(),
        "email"=>$worksheet->getCell('D'.$r)->getCalculatedValue(),
        "block"=>0,
        "groups"=>array("1","2")    // 1=Public, 2=Registered
    );

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($udate as $k=>$v){
        echo'<td>'.$v.'</td>';
    }
    if($doImport) {
        $user = new JUser;
        if(!$user->bind($udata)) {
            throw new Exception("Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError());
        }
        if (!$user->save()) {
            throw new Exception("Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError());
        }
        $new_user_id = $user->id;
        echo'<td>'.$new_user_id.'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: above explain better my question

Answer (score 0):

Since you placed the 3rd party library in the libraries directory, this is actually just one line of code to load it:

```
jimport('simpleexcel.src.simpleexcel.simpleexcel');
```

You can use jimport to import any php file located in Joomla's root libraries folder.  Folder delineations are marked with periods, exclude the libraries folder as it is assumed and everything should be lowercase.

*** EDIT 1 ***

You can use the below link of code to retrieve the files inside the request object in Joomla.  In the example below, filename is the from input name attribute.

```
$file = JRequest::getVar('filename', null, 'files', 'array');
```

Since this looks like an issue with retrieving files from a form submission, it might help if you could post the code for generating the form.  Are you using a Joomla xml form definition file or building it out manually? Below is a link for Joomla doc regarding file uploads for reference.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

Comment: had already tried to import it but I also do not do it either

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing with joomla MVC, the model I have a xml file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>  
        <field name="seleccione" type="file" class="inputbox" accept="xls"
            label="COM_EMPRESA_FORM_LBL_CARGA_MASIVA" description="COM_EMPRESA_FORM_DESC_CARGA_MASIVA"
             required="true" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

and in view default.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @package     com_empresa
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2014. Todos los derechos reservados.
 * @license     Licencia Pública General GNU versión 2 o posterior. Consulte LICENSE.txt
 * @author      Rafael Gasperi <rafael.gasperi@sipeca.net> - http://www.tcontacta.com
 */
// no direct access

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
//$document->addStyleSheet(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_empresa/assets/css/empresa.css');

JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');

//Load admin language file
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_empresa', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
?>

<!-- Styling for making front end forms look OK -->
<!-- This should probably be moved to the template CSS file -->

<style>
.front-end-edit ul {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.front-end-edit li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 6px !important;
}

.front-end-edit label {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 200px !important;
}

.front-end-edit .radio label {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px !important;
}

.front-end-edit .readonly {
    border: none !important;
    color: #666;
}

.front-end-edit #editor-xtd-buttons {
    height: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
}

.front-end-edit .toggle-editor {
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    float: right;
}

#jform_rules-lbl {
    display: none;
}

#access-rules a:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5 url('../images/slider_minus.png') right top
        no-repeat;
    color: #444;
}

</style>

<div class="empresa-edit front-end-edit">

 <form id="form-cargar" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_empresa&task=cargamasiva.mostrar'); ?>" method="post" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
        <div class="control-group"> 
        <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_TITULO_EMPLEADOS'); ?> </legend>  

                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('seleccione'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('seleccione'); ?></div>

            </div>
         <div class="fltlft" <?php if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.admin','empresa')): ?> style="display:none;" <?php endif; ?> >
                <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.start', 'permissions-sliders-'.$this->item->id, array('useCookie'=>1)); ?>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.panel', JText::_('ACL Configuration'), 'access-rules'); ?>
                <fieldset class="panelform">
                    <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('rules'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('rules'); ?>
                </fieldset>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.end'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.admin','empresa')): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery('.tab-pane select').each(function(){
               var option_selected = jQuery(this).find(':selected');
               var input = document.createElement("input");
               input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
               input.setAttribute("name", jQuery(this).attr('name'));
               input.setAttribute("value", option_selected.val());
               document.getElementById("form-empresa").appendChild(input);
               jQuery(this).attr('disabled',true);
            });
            </script>
         <?php endif; ?>
         </form>
          <form id="form-empresa" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_empresa&task=cargamasiva.save'); ?>" method="post" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">        


            <div>
              <button id="jform_btnCargar" class="btn tip" type="button" class="hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_CARGAR'); ?>">
              <i class="icon-checkmark"></i> <span><?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_CARGAR'); ?></span> </button>
            </div>

            <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_EMPLEADOS'); ?> </legend>
            <div class="empresa-edit front-end-edit-list">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="jform_cargamasivaList" name="jform[cargamasivaList]" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="1%" class="hidden-phone">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="checkall-toggle" value="" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_CHECK_ALL'); ?>" onclick="checkAll();" />
                    </th>
                    <th class='left'>
                        <?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_CEDULA') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class='left'>
                        <?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_NOMBRE') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class='left'>
                        <?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_APELLIDO') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class='left'>
                        <?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_CORREO') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class='left'>
                        <?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_GENERO') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class='left'>
                        <?php echo JText::_('COM_EMPRESA_CARGA_MASIVA_FECHA_NACIMIENTO') ?>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="bodyEmpleados" >

            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

         <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn validate"><i class="icon-save"></i><span><?php echo JText::_('JPROCESAR'); ?></span></button>
            <a class="btn" href=" <?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_empresa&task=empresa.cancel'); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?>">
            <i class="icon-cancel"></i> <?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?></a>

         </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">



    function validarExtension(){
        alert("entro");


        var archivo = document.getElementById('jform_seleccione').value;
        if(archivo!= ""){
            extension = (archivo.substring(archivo.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase(); 
            if(extension!=".xls"){
                alert("El Archivo a cargar debe ser Excel en version 2003 (.xls)");
            }else{
                var fic = archivo.split('\\');
                var nombre=fic[fic.length-1]; 
            }
        }else{
            alert("No ha cargado ningún archivo");
            }
    }

    function getScript(url,success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        done = false;
        // Attach handlers for all browsers
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState
                || this.readyState == 'loaded'
                || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                success();
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
            }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
    }



    getScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',function() {
     js = jQuery.noConflict();
        js(document).ready(function(){

   js("#jform_btnCargar").click(function()
            {  
    var archivo = document.getElementById('jform_seleccione').value;
    var fic = archivo.split('\\');
    var nombre=fic[fic.length-1];

    js.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "index.php?option=com_empresa&task=cargamasiva.mostrar",
        data:"nombre="+nombre,
        datatype:"application/json",               
        success: function(data){      
        alert("entro js");                 
                var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
                alert("data"+data);   
                alert(objData.valores[4]);    
                if (objData.error == 1){                    
                    procesarCarga('jform_cargamasivaList', objData.valores);
                    alert("salio pa controller");  
                } 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error ajax");
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(jqXHR);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
       });
            });
        });
});




//    getScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',function() {
//       js = jQuery.noConflict();
//      //   js(document).ready(function(){
//    
//    js("#jform_btnCargar").click(function()
//    {
//      var archivo = document.getElementById('jform_seleccione').value;
//      var fic = archivo.split('\\');
//      var nombre=fic[fic.length-1];
//      validarExtension();
//
//      js.ajax({
//          type:"POST",
//          url: "index.php?option=com_empresa&task=cargamasiva.mostrar",
//          data:"nombre="+js("#jform_seleccione").val(),
//          datatype:"application/json",               
//          success: function(data){      
//          alert("entro js");         
//              var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
//              alert("data"+objData);        
//              if (objData.error == 1){                    
//                  procesarCarga('jform_cargamasivaList', objData.valores);
//              } 
//          },
//          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//              alert("error ajax");
//              alert(textStatus);
//              alert(jqXHR);
//              alert(errorThrown);
//          }
//        });
//          });
//        // });
//});
function procesarCarga(tableID, valores) {
    document.getElementById('bodyEmpleados').innerHTML = "";
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

//  var archivo = document.getElementById('jform_seleccione').value;
//  var fic = archivo.split('\\');
//  var nombre=fic[fic.length-1];
//  alert(nombre); 

<?php 
  try {
    $filas=file('nombre.txt');
    // iniciamos contador y la fila a cero
    $i=0;
    $numero_fila=0;
    // mientras exista una fila
    while($filas[$i]!=NULL){
    // incremento contador de la fila
    $row = $filas[$i+1]; 
    // genero array con por medio del separador "," que es el que tiene el archivo txt
    $sql = explode(",",$row);
    // incrementamos contador
    $i++;
    $numero_fila++;
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "mostrar";
  }
?>

    alert(valores[1]);
    alert(valores[2]);
    alert(valores[0]);
    alert("5");

//   var numero = "<?php echo $row[0]; ?>";
//   
//   var fechaVencimiento = "<?php echo "hola";?>";
//   var pais = "<?php echo "hola";?>";
//   var idPaisEmision = "<?php echo "-gtr";?>";


    var numero = valores[0];
    var fechaVencimiento =valores[1];
    var pais = valores[2];
    var idPaisEmision = valores[3];
    var numero = valores[4];
    var numero = valores[5];

    var idPaisEmision = "holis";

    var empleados = '<tr class="row' + (rowCount % 2) + '" ><td class="center hidden-phone"><?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', '', ''); ?></td><td>'+numero+'</td>'
            +'<td>'+fechaVencimiento+'</td><td>'+pais+'</td></tr>'+'</td><td>'+idPaisEmision+'</td></tr>';
            document.getElementById('bodyEmpleados').innerHTML = document.getElementById('bodyEmpleados').innerHTML + empleados;

    }


</script>
```

---

thus management view